# ¿Cómo realizar una busqueda excluyendo una(s) palabra(s)?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo dos `input text` para realizar búsquedas en dos tablas de mi base de datos, específicamente el título y la descripción... en el primer `input` coloco la(s) palabra(s) a buscar y me funciona, pero ahora necesito que al colocar la(s) segunda(s) en el segundo `input` me excluya de la búsqueda dichas palabras.

Ejemplo:

- Música
- Salsa...

Me haga búsquedas de música exceptuando las que contengan la palabra salsa en el título y/o descripción.

Tengo lo siguiente en mi controlador:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $videos = Video::search($request->buscar)
                        ->paginate(12);
        return view('results', compact('videos'));
    }
```

En mi modelo:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $find)
    {
        $search = explode(" ", $find);
        $total = count($search);

        $array = array();
        for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++ ) {
             if( $i == 0 ) {
                  $array = $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(title, ' ', description)"), "LIKE", "%".Stemm_es::stemm($search[$i])."%");
              } else {
                  $array = $array->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(title, ' ', description)"), "LIKE", "%".Stemm_es::stemm($search[$i])."%");
              }
        }

        return $array;

    }
```

No sé si `Eloquent` o `Sql` tengan alguna opción para solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato usas en tus tablas para almacenar el título y la descripción?

Comment: En el campo titulo "String" y en Descripción "Text".

Comment: Son solo dos campos de búsqueda, o pueden ser más input?

Comment: Son solo dos inputs

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría un pluck de exclusión a la primera búsqueda de elementos. Lo haría de la siguiente manera desde el controlador (después puedes aplicar la misma lógica al scope del modelo)

```
public function search(Request $r)
{
    //Indexo por parámetro 1, que sería el título
    $lista = explode(' ', $r->input1);
    $lista2 = explode(' ',$r->input2);
    $videos = Video::whereIn('titulo',$items)->get();

    if($videos->count() > 0){
        $excluir = $videos->pluck('titulo');
        $resultado = Video::whereIn('titulo',$lista2)->whereNotIn('descripcion',$excluir)->get();

        return view('results', ['videos'=>$resultado]);
    }


    return view('results', compact('videos'));
}
```

Comment: Gracias, voy a intentarlo y te aviso. Gracias

Comment: No, no funciona... Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Consideremos lo siguiente:

> Al tener que exlcluir de un campo de tipo `VARCHAR` tu consulta se puede componer de esta forma:

Muestra:

```
Modelo::whereNotIn('titulo', [$request->titulo])
```

- Es decir al ser un campo de texto *simple* le indicamos el nombre de la columna
- Como segundo argumento le pasamos un vector de valores y en este caso será el valor que lea `$request` de lo que le llegue del front del valor `titulo` **asumiendo que así se llame en tu formulario, sino modificalo**

> Para el asunto de la descripción es un tanto distinto, pues:

- Puede ser un texto amplio
- La palabra que servirá de filtro puede estar al inicio, al medio o al final
- Laravel provee un [método por medio de Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scout#introduction) para la búsqueda en textos
- Podemos aplicar *FULL TEXT SEARCH* pero será a nivel del *query builder* **ya que esto solo es característico de MySQL y MariaDB** por lo que no existe dentro de los métodos genéricos que ofrece el ORM Eloquent

> Importante, recuerda siempre antes de hacer algún cambio en tu base de datos realizar un respaldo

A tu tabla le puedes agregar desde tu gestor un cambio para que la declaración quede de esta forma:

```
ALTER TABLE tuTabla ADD FULLTEXT(descripcion);
```

Ahora para poder realizar la búsqueda de descartando una palabra que se encuentre en la descripción tendriamos que hacer uso *de un `where` que permita el paso de una consulta en SQL puro* para ejecutar la búsqueda con el formato que ofrece el motor de bases de datos:

```
Modelo::whereNotIn('titulo', [$request->titulo])
      ->whereRaw('NOT MATCH (descripcion) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)', [$request->description])
      ->get();
```

Básicamente lo que hacemos:

- Usamos `whereNotIn()` para buscar filtrando por los valores que no tengan dicha palabra
- Usamos el método `whereRaw`para indicar una segunda condición obligatoria donde diremos que seleccione de la columna `descripcion` los que **no empaten** contra el valor que colocamos indicado por el símbolo de **`?`** mismo que después será sustituido por el valor que pasamos entre corchetes al final de esa misma línea

**REFERENCIAS**

- [FullText](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)
- [whereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods)

Comment: Gracias, voy a intentarlo y te aviso. Gracias

Comment: muy bien @Joseph quedo atento a tu respuesta

Comment: La verdad no encuentro la manera de incluirlos, ya que en el controlador va esta consulta: $videos = Video::search($request->buscar) y donde debo agregarlos es en el scope (ver el modelo en la pregunta).

Comment: Las recomendaciones que te hago son a nivel del motor de bases de datos

Comment: Sí sustituyo el where del modelo por whereNotIn, me da el siguiente error: `TypeError
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given`